# extract properties from array of objects and store in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

i have an array of objects that is coming from server.

```
data:[
   {
    // values
   }
]
```

below is one object element of that array.

```
0:
assignedTo:{
name: "Shokat iqbal"
},

category:{
name: "Fan"
},

complainer:{
name: "Testt"
},

details: "Makk Amjum and my name is yeh and i amthose who is ur father"

location: "Room number 87 blockasdas jknaksdnkaj knasdkan kasndka nasdkas"

status: "in-progress"

title: "My fan is damaged"

_id: "5cade948e0b7ce30c8ef2f05"
```

i want to extract some of its properties like

```
Assignee: assignedTo.name, category: Category.name, Complainer:complainer.name
```

and want to make another array of objects which will look like this.

```
[
  {
   Assignee: assignedTo.name,
   Complainer: complainer.name,
   Category: category.name,
   title: title,
   location: location,
   details: details
  }
]
```

please help me how to do this?

Comment: This is a basic problem! You can do it with a loop

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  It's always good to try and show, or talk about some of the solutions that you have tried and where they failed.  The community is great but they also appreciate people trying.

Array.map will do the trick for you

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
const formattedData = data.map(record => ({
  Assignee: record.assignedTo.name,
  Complainer: record.complainer.name,
  Category: record.category.name,
  title: record.title,
  location: record.location,
  details: record.details,
}));
```